# Mounted SMB shares: permission troubles with UID mismatch between client and server

Tags: permissions, smb, uid

On the Linux machine *LinuxClient* I'm trying to mount an SMB share *backups* located on the Unix machine *Server*.
I want to provide separate directories within *backups* for different purposes, and I want to set restrictive permissions on those subdirectories (access only for owner):

```
backups (accessible to all users in group backups)
backups/LinuxClient (accessible only to _LinuxUser_)
backups/OtherClient (accessible only to _OtherUser_)
```

*Server* and *LinuxClient* have separate user accounts with different, but overlapping UIDs. Out of necessity, *LinuxUser* has different UIDs on *LinuxClient* and *Server*.

To resolve this, I have created network-wide groups *net-backups* and *net-LinuxUser* with GIDs that are the same on all machines, and added *LinuxUser* to both groups on *LinuxClient* and on *Server*.

I have set the following permissions on the directories:

```
root@server:/ # ls -la backups
total 27
drwxr-x---   5 root       net-backups     6 Aug  9 09:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 root       root           11 Aug  3 17:56 ..
drwxrwx---   2 LinuxUser  net-LinuxUser   2 Aug  9 09:13 LinuxClient
```

I have successfully mounted *backups* on *LinuxClient*.

Why am I still getting Permission denied when trying to cd into /mnt/backups as *LinuxUser*, but not as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'uh. Turns out reloading the user session did the trick.

*group* and *id* weren't showing the new groups either until I logged in again.